# multiple Vrapper buttons on eclipse toolbar

Tags: vim, eclipse-plugin

Shortly after I installed Vrapper for eclispe with a few plugins the vrapper activation button on the toolbar started to replicate. First there were 2 buttons and now there's 3. I tried to remove Vrapper and then to reinstall it, but the 3 buttons popped back up immeidately.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: I am running eclipse kepler on windows

Comment: Vrapper's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=closed).

Comment: @romainl: I think you should add your reference to issue tracker as answer not as comment, or we will end up with plenty of unanwsered questions in the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of issue is generally more suited to issue trackers.

Vrapper recently moved its development to GitHub so, [there you go](https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=closed).